# Attaching style to feature after drawing

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using `ol.Interaction.Draw` to draw polygons atop a map. I want to style the individual features after they're drawn.

When I detect a `DRAWEND` event, I try to attach a style to the last feature drawn, but only the general layer styling appears onscreen, although I see it when I search in the feature itself via the debugger.

```
map.addInteraction( drawInter = new ol.interaction.Draw({           
                features: drawLayer.getFeatures(),                      
                type: "Polygon" 
                })                                                  
            );

drawInter.on('drawend', function(e) {                           
    var style = new ol.style.Style({                                    
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: newColor })
        });

    var features = drawLayer.getFeatures().getArray();                  
    var last = features.length-1;
    features[last].setStyle(style); 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature you call `setStyle` on is not the one that was just drawn. This is why the feature that was just drawn doesn't have the expected style. (And given your code I am actually surprised the feature persists on the map when the drawing is finished.)

Your code is incorrect/strange in multiple ways:

- Reading your code it sounds like you think that each call to `getFeatures` on the vector layer returns the same array. It's not the case. Each call to `getFeatures` actually returns a new array.
- You pass an array of features to the Draw interaction (through the `features` option). This is incorrect. The `features` option should an `ol.Collection`.
- In the `drawend` callback the event object (`e` in your code) includes a reference to the drawn feature (`e.feature`).

So, if you want to persist the drawn features into a vector layer, you can use the following:

```js
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  type: 'Polygon',
  source: drawLayer.getSource()
});

draw.on('drawend', function(e) {
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    // ...
  });
  e.feature.setStyle(style);
});

map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Comment: I was working off off the `Draw and modify features example` on the site, and have defined my layer like this:

`drawLayer=new ol.FeatureOverlay({ source: new ol.source.Vector() } );`

and this yields an error using the `'source: drawLayer.getSource()` method.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I changed the drawlayer initialization to:

`drawLayer=new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector() });
map.addLayer(this.drawLayer)`
and I can style the feature now, but when I add the modifyInteraction:

`map.addInteraction( this.modifyInter=new ol.interaction.Modify({y
        source: drawLayer.getSource()`
I get an error whenever this code is loaded:

_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at ol-debug.js:90285_

Comment: This is a different problem. The `Modify` interaction requires an `ol.Collection`, specified through the `features` option. This collection includes the candidates for modification.